# Variable assignment in class scope works in React but not in ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, syntax, scope

This ReactJS code is valid and produces the desired output:

```
import React from 'react'

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {'x': 1}

  render() {
    console.log('render: this.state:', this.state)
    return <div>{this.state.x}</div>
  }
}

export default MyComponent
```

But this very similar ES6 code causes error when running with Node.js:

```
class MyComponent {
  state = {'x': 1}

  render() {
    console.log('render: this.state:', this.state)
    return <div>{this.state.x}</div>
  }
}

let c = new MyComponent()
c.render()
```

Here is the error:

```
$ node foo.js 
/Users/lone/foo.js:2
  state = {'x': 1}
        ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
```

Why does the second example lead to error when the first example runs fine with ReactJS?

Comment: That's not "ES6" code. It's technically not even ES-anything yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That syntax is not yet a standard part of javascript (it's currently a [stage 3 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields)). It can be used with the help of [babel's class-properties plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties) to transpile it into standard javascript. Most likely  your react project includes this plugin, which is why it works for you in react. Create-react-app, for example, includes the plugin. Without the plugin, react can't use that syntax either.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, this is not yet standard and create-react-app has a transpilation babel plugin. But you could make it work by using a flag on Node >= 10.9. The flag is `--js-flags="--harmony"`.

[Source](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/esnext/#test-instance_class_fields_public_instance_class_fields)